# MongoDB Insert Script CMD Can't Parse £ Symbol

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a batch script to insert data into MongoDB. The issue I'm having is that £ becomes ┬ú when the data is in the DB.

The escape character for ' is \' and for % is %% but both of these don't help with the pound sign.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Example statement below:

```
echo.
echo updating systemparameter table

set parameter=AdhocFeeMaximumFeeAmount

call :Check_Items_Exists_Func %parameter% found

echo Does %parameter% exist? %found%

IF "%found%"=="FALSE" (
  echo Inserting %parameter%

  Mongo %dbserver%/%dbname% %usr% %pwd% --eval "db.systemparameter.insert({'_id':'AdhocFeeMaximumFeeAmount','BusinessRuleDefinition':{'ErrorMessageFormat':'The maximum adhoc fee up to £10k is £50','Severity':'Error'},'Description':'Maximum Fee Amount less than or equal to £100k','ParameterType':'BusinessRule','Value':'100'})"
)
```

Comment: £ is not a special character, maybe it's a collation or encoding problem, I mean what's the collation of your databases? what's the Windows locale you are using?, as a wild guess maybe the data is inserted correctly and just your application can't display the £ sign correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by substituting £ for \u00A3 in the script